# Stuck timestamp on log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm using *log4net* library,v 2.0.2, for logging, .Net 4, server service.
This server has non stop running and write operation events to a rolling log file.

Occasionally, I'm having a problem of stuck timestamp records on my server log file. 
The logger keep write messages into file but the message timestamp is stucks on the same datetime. The datetime milliseconds are keep increasing on rolling back.
Can't reproduce bug on my environment and I didn't found such bug on [log4net forums](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Log4net-f19151.html)

Attached example:

```
    2015-12-18 00:18:08,835 [59] INFO  ServiceA - info message
    2015-12-18 00:18:08,897 [50] WARN  ServiceB - warning message
    2015-12-18 00:18:08,032 [15] INFO  ServiceA - another info message
    2015-12-18 00:18:08,094 [27] ERROR ServiceC - some error occured
    2015-12-18 00:18:08,148 [19] ERROR ServiceC - another error
    2015-12-18 00:18:08,342 [6] WARN  ServiceA - another warning message
```

Did some one had encountered with such problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing the DateTime.Now in the log message to check it's not a time of the pc issue?

Comment: can you add log4net configuration section?

Comment: The logged timestamp is the _time when the log event was created_ and not when it is actually logged. If you have multiple processes writing to the same file, then each will have to wait for it's turn to be able to write, resulting in log entries that appear to be out of order.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
 
I found that all DateTime related writings have strange values. For example, for measuring internal app operations we taking the start and the end times, by using DateTime.Now, and we are writing the elapsed time to log. The measured times ranges appear as '00:00:00', '-00:00:00.0020002', '-00:00:00.0010001'